# Type Elmish.WPF main() function reports binding () -> #Window as an error

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

Why does my version of the Elmish.WPF Sample NewWindow ([XAML code](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow) and [F# Core](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core)) emit the error ...

- *The type 'unit -> 'a' is not compatible with the type 'Window'.*

The same line emits the warning...

- *This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' or other type annotation at or near <line reference to createWindow_Window2 in the let bindings = statement">*

**Why am I getting this error and warning?**

What I am doing is merging the Elmish.WPF Samples SingleCounter  ([XAML code](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/SingleCounter) and [F# Core](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/SingleCounter.Core)) and NewWindow ([XAML code](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow) and [F# Core](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core)) to have the `Model`, `bindings()`, and `Msg` parts in `Program.fs` instead of `App.fs` (as it was in the NewWindow sample).

My goal is to make a SimpleCounter able to open a NewWindow.

The XAML code passes `Func<Window2>` into the F# code here...

```
let main mainWindow (createWindow2: Func<#Window>)
```

...I define `bindings` as...

```
let bindings = Platform.bindings createWindow_Window2
```

I am down to the one compiler error I mentioned above (and that also appears in line beginning "let bindings = ..." below)...

```
let main mainWindow (createWindow_Window2: Func<#Window>) =

  let logger =
      LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Update", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Bindings", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Performance", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger()
  let createWindow_Window2 = 
      let window = createWindow_Window2.Invoke()
      window.Owner <- mainWindow
      window

  let bindings = Platform.bindings createWindow_Window2
  WpfProgram.mkProgramWithCmdMsg (fun _ -> m_init, []) update bindings toCmd
    |> WpfProgram.withLogger (new SerilogLoggerFactory(logger))
    |> WpfProgram.startElmishLoop mainWindow
```

The top of `Program.bindings` is defined as ...

```
 let bindings (createWindow_Window2: unit -> #Window) () : Binding<Model, Msg> list = [
        "Window_Window2_Show|> Binding.cmd Window_AboutProduct_Show
        "Window_Window2" |> Binding.subModelWin(
                                                Window_Window2.get >> WindowState.ofOption,
                                                snd,
                                                Window_Window2ct.mapInOutMsg,
                                                Window_Window2_Module.Window_Window2.bindings,
                                                createWindow_Window2,
                                                isModal = true)
...bindings continue but are not relevant to this question...
```

... *and reports no errors!*

*The compiler seems to think `Platform.bindings` is expecting `` unit -> `a `` when `createWindow_Window2` is correctly typed as `unit -> #Window`.*

You can see the call *into* `Program.fs:main` is correctly called from `App.xaml.cs` with a lambda function returning a `Window2` as follows...

```
        private void StartElmish(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activated -= StartElmish;
            Program.main(MainWindow, () => new Window2());
        }
```

*So my question is why am I getting this mismatch type error when it seems I am passing the correct types?*

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a GitHub repo with your code, so we can easily reproduce what you're seeing? IMHO, it's a little too difficult to follow your description otherwise.

Comment: It says Func<#Window2> in one place. What happens if you just write Window there instead of Window2?

Comment: @BentTranberg - thank you but that was a typo.  I just now fixed the typo.

Comment: @BrianBerns - Good idea.  I am adding a new Sample to the Elmish.WPF repo with this problem.  Maybe it will be usefully instructional for others.

Comment: I don't think that will be accepted. From what I understand the samples there are meant to be just the minimal needed to demonstrate functionality in Elmish.WPF, and pretty much nothing beyond that. I have created my own demos on GitHub, but I'm not very good at maintaining them, and the older ones likely has a bunch of flaws, though might still be useful. I haven't tried anything like this Q.

Comment: If you ask a question in the Elmish.WPF repo, you're likely to get very good answers. But you're likely to be asked to have a repro in a repo then.

Comment: @BentTranberg Thank you for the warning.  My contribution will be in the spirit of: https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/issues/419  If needs to be improved or expanded to satisfy #419 that will be just fine.  If it must be in a separate repo that is fine too.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'd love to contribute too if there's a place I can add samples. Perhaps we'll continue discussing in the Elmish.WPF issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank you to: Brian Berns, Bent Tranberg, and Tomas Petricek for helping me!

The answer to my problem was astonishingly simple to an expert but to a relative novice only yielded after meticulous comparison with the working Elmish.WPF code for NewWindow.

For easy comparison I have pushed up to [rfreytag/Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF) a version of the NewWindow (XAML code and [F# Core](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/tree/SO72821585_App_code_placed_in_Program_file/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core)) sample that compiles and runs *(REMEMBER to build the NewWindow sample).*

This version of NewWindow ([XAML code](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/tree/SO72821585_App_code_placed_in_Program_file_WITH_ERROR/src/Samples/NewWindow) and [F# Core](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/tree/SO72821585_App_code_placed_in_Program_file_WITH_ERROR/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core)) when compiled shows the *error* and *warning* I reported above …

```
The type 'unit -> 'a' is not compatible with the type 'Window'. 
See also C:\Workspace\Elmish.WPF\src\Samples\AnotherNewWindow.Core\Program.fs(78,72)-(78,79).
```

...and the warning...

```
This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its 
type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' 
or other type annotation at or near 
'C:\Workspace\Elmish.WPF\src\Samples\AnotherNewWindow.Core\Program.fs(78,72)-(78,79)' 
has been constrained to be type 'unit -> 'a'.
```

To see the precise fix you can [compare the working and breaking branches on my copy of Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/compare/SO72821585_App_code_placed_in_Program_file...rfreytag:Elmish.WPF:SO72821585_App_code_placed_in_Program_file_WITH_ERROR).  Which is that I had forgotten the `()` following the definition of `let createWindow_Window2 =` ...

```
let createWindow_Window2 = 
      let window = createWindow_Window2.Invoke()
      window.Owner <- mainWindow
      window
```

... returns the function `() -> Window` while the correct ...

```
let createWindow_Window2 () = 
      let window = createWindow_Window2.Invoke()
      window.Owner <- mainWindow
      window
```

... returns the needed `Window`.

A newbie looks at `unit → ‘a` and doesn’t immediately recognize it as a function.  And of course, functions are not C# `Window` objects.

Did not help me that the error message doesn’t follow the F# form of...

```
expecting a <type sought by context> 
but was given a <passed in type>
```

...which has become familiar from working with the F# compiler.

Not sure why this message diverged from that pattern.  Maybe someone can explain that?

The warning is alerting to the less-specific `#Window` (see [# ‘flexible type’ definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types)) possibly clashing at run-time with the `unit → ‘a` function.

As usual, learning a new framework means learning the compiler and linker messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think one issue in your code is that the name `createWindow_Window2` is used both as the name of an argument of `main`, but then later also as a local variable in the function of differnt type. Another issue is that in one place, you try to use a delegate type `Func<#Window>` but in another place, you have an ordinary F# function `Window -> unit`.

My advice would be to use `Window -> unit` everywhere and avoid variable shadowing:

```ml
let main mainWindow (createWindow_Window2:Window -> unit) = (* Changed type here *)
  let logger = (* omitted *)
  let createWindowWithOwner () =  
        (* Renamed and added '()' so that it is a function *)
      let window = createWindow_Window2 () (* Just function call *)
      window.Owner <- mainWindow
      window

  let bindings = 
    Platform.bindings createWindowWithOwner (* Pass the right function here *)
  (* omitted *)
```

Comment: Good idea Tomas to avoid createWindow_Window2 variable shadowing, but changing to ```let createWindowWithOwner () =``` has no effect.  Also, using ```Window -> unit``` causes ```let window =``` to assign ```window``` as ```unit``` causing the next line ```window.Owner <- mainWindow``` to fail as ```window``` is now ```unit```.  Do you mean ```unit -> Window``` instead of ```Window -> unit```?  Fundamentally, I am unclear about the use of ```Func<#Window>``` and so don't know why I am being *warned* it is less generic.